# How to order data frame columns alphabetically and numerically in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
A1 <- c(1,2,5)
B1 <- c(6,2,4)
C1 <- c(4,1,3)
A2 <- c(3,8,9)
B2 <- c(1,2,3)
C2 <- c(2,6,9)

df_1 <- data.frame(A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2)
```

How can I reorder the columns as I have below?

```
df_2 <- data.frame(A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `parse_number` to extract the names and order

```
library(dplyr)
df1_1 <- df_1 %>% 
   select(order(readr::parse_number(names(.)), names(.))
```

-output

```
  A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
1  1  6  4  3  1  2
2  2  2  1  8  2  6
3  5  4  3  9  3  9
```

---

Or using `base R` - get the numeric part with `sub`, and `order` separately the numeric first

```
df_1[order(as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", names(df_1))), names(df_1))]
  A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
1  1  6  4  3  1  2
2  2  2  1  8  2  6
3  5  4  3  9  3  9
```